# Data Validation going from specific column to end

Tags: excel

So I have this column in my worksheet that ,by the use of data validation, has a drop-down menu of the items in another worksheet.

This is the line "of code" that I use for the drop-down menu `=DataSheet!$1:$1`

But it also lists the items in the first few columns. Which I do not want.

What I have tried for that is the following `=DataSheet!($1.Offset(,6)):$1`. From my experience with VBA I thought this might work.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you just do `=DataSheet!$E1:$XFD$1`, etc.?

Comment: Is `XFD` the last possible column in excel?

Comment: @dwirony, thank you very much! It's fine this way.

Comment: @MateoVD Yes it is the last possible column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to dynamically populate the list from the kth column and stopping at the last populated column (assuming no gaps) then

```
=OFFSET(DataSheet!A1,0,6,1,COUNTA(DataSheet!1:1)-6)
```

[`OFFSET`s](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) parameters:

1. **Reference**: Start counting from cell `A1`
2. **Rows**: Move `0` rows down
3. **Columns**: Move `6` columns to the left
4. **Height**: Make a range that is `1` row high.
5. **Width**: Make a range that is `COUNTA(1:1)-6` columns wide. `COUNTA(1:1)` returns the number of non-empty cells in row `1`, but because we're skipping the first `6` columns (i.e. the **Columns** parameter), we subtract `6` from this to find out how wide the range needs to be such that it goes from column `7` to the last value in the row.

Comment: Can you please explain what which part in this line does? So I can apply it in future projects

Comment: @MateoVD I think it's pretty clear from [the docs](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) but I've added an explanation now

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. But this won't work because it doesn't reference the `DataSheet` Worksheet.

Comment: I'll update while Dan's wiping up the tea he just spat over his desk.... all his formula is missing is the worksheet reference in front of the cell references the same as any other formula that references another sheet.  `=OFFSET(DataSheet!A1,0,6,1,COUNTA(DataSheet!1:1)-6)`  Sorry to sound sarcastic, but you do have 4 years of coding experience and referencing other sheets in Excel is a day 1 thing.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook That's why it says "and I'm still a beginner.". I just couldn't find it in the documents. I knew it had to be somewhere. Please don't get me wrong in all this. I appreciate the help a lot.

Comment: Fair enough.  My apologies.